# Automapper 5 - map Nullable<T> to T with condition

Tags: c#, automapper

I would like to map `Nullable<T>` to `T`, but only if the source value is not `null`. In case of `null` I want to preserve the destination value. So I set up a mapping with `.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition((src, dst, srcVal, dstVal) => srcVal != null))`. This is working for reference types like `string`, but not for `Nullable<T>`. If the source value of type `int?` is `null` then `srcVal` in the condition is `0`. Therefore `true` is returned and the destination value is overwritten.

How can I prevent the mapping of a property of type `Nullable<T>` when its value is `null`?

Here is the code:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MapperConfigurationExpression mce = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
        mce.CreateMap<Src, Dst>()
           .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition((src, dst, srcVal, dstVal) => srcVal != null));
        MapperConfiguration configuration = new MapperConfiguration(mce);
        configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        IMapper mapper = new Mapper(configuration);

        Src s = new Src();
        Dst d = mapper.Map<Dst>(s);

        Console.WriteLine($"Text: {d.Text}, Int: {d.Int}, Short: {d.Short}");
    }
}

public class Src
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int? Int { get; set; }
    public short? Short { get; set; }
}

public class Dst
{
    Dst()
    {
        Text = "Default";
        Int = 300;
        Short = 10;
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Int { get; set; }
    public short Short { get; set; }
}
```